# Execute action when combobox item is selected FXML

Tags: javafx, combobox, fxml

I'm trying to create a drop down menu (using ComboBox) with FXML and JavaFX controllers.

This is what I already have:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="menuSettings" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="27.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">               
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Menu" />
            <String fx:value="Settings" />
            <String fx:value="Exit" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

How can I show a new scene using Action listeners when the ComboBox option is selected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways that come to mind on how you could do this.

The first would be to add the `onAction="#yourMethod"` to your `<ComboBox ... >` tag. You could then add some code to your controller...

```
@FXML public void yourMethod() {
    //Show the scene here
}
```

...which would be run when the user selected an item.

The other thing that you could do would be to add a `ChangeListener` to your ComboBox:

```
@FXML public void initialize() {
    yourComboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue value, String old, String new) {
                //Show your scene here
            }    
        });
}
```

Both of these work I think, it's just a matter of preference to do it in code or FXML.

I hope this was helpful, and good luck with your project!

(If this did not answer your question, please let me know and I will do my best to revise my answer)